# Simple animation in React doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add simple cloud animation in my React from this codepen: https://codepen.io/antonioescudero/pen/zrxGve

However, it doesn't work, I feel the issue is more related to React itself, whether I'm missing or need to add something.

In my app I have Slick React slider, so I'm not sure if it's related to the issue.

I also try to create separate folder without React just pure HTML and CSS, and the animation is working fine so I know the issue is not with the animation.

```css
*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    /*To hide the horizontal scroller appearing during the animation*/
    overflow: hidden;
}

.clouds{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: #c9dbe9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c9dbe9 0%, #fff 100%);
}
/*Time to finalise the cloud shape*/
.cloud {
    width: 200px; height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    
    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    
    position: relative; 
}

.cloud:before, .cloud:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; 
    background: #fff;
    width: 100px; height: 80px;
    position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 10px;
    
    border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cloud:after {
    width: 120px; height: 120px;
    top: -55px; left: auto; right: 15px;
}

/*Time to animate*/
.x1 {
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear infinite;
}

/*variable speed, opacity, and position of clouds for realistic effect*/
.x2 {
    left: 200px;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
    transform: scale(0.6);
    opacity: 0.6; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
    
    /*Speed will also be proportional to the size and opacity*/
    /*More the speed. Less the time in 's' = seconds*/
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite;
}

.x3 {
    left: -250px; top: -200px;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
    
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

.x4 {
    left: 470px; top: -250px;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 0.75; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
    
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 18s linear infinite;
}

.x5 {
    left: -150px; top: -150px;
    
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.8; /*opacity proportional to the size*/
    
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

```html
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css'
import './HeroSection.css';

import data from './HeroData';

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function HeroSection() {

    const [test, setTest] = useState(data);

    const settings = {
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1000,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows: true,
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        className: "slides"
    }

    return (
        <div className="hero-container">
            <div className="hero-container-wrap-child">
                <div className="hero-container-slider-wrapper">
                    <Slider {...settings}>
                        {test.map((testData) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={testData.id} className="hero-container-data-wrapper">
                                    <img alt="customAlt" src={testData.image} />
                                    <p>{testData.name} </p>
                                    <p>{testData.age} years</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </Slider>
                </div>

            </div>
            
            <div className="clouds">
                <div className="cloud x1"></div>
                <div className="cloud x2"></div>
                <div className="cloud x3"></div>
                <div className="cloud x4"></div>
                <div className="cloud x5"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default HeroSection;
```